# Create PHP Variables for all columns in SQL query

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I have a PHP file that will run a SQL select statement and echo out the results. I am trying to be able to set individual columns to specific variables. Is this possible?

IE: based on the code below, how could I create a variable called $FirstName and set it equal to the value of the single record in the column firstname that is returned?

Thank you

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Employees where Employee_ID = 1";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $trpConn, $sql );
  if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
  }

  while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['FirstName'].", ".$row['LastName']."<br />";
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with the array? You could use `extract()` but that will only lead to problems as you can overwrite existing variables, etc. Even the php manual recommends against using it.

Comment: If you want to store the value in a variable just make `$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];` before your `echo` statement.

Comment: Thank you @Error404 - too simple but that is exactly what I was trying to do but I was putting it in the wrong location before. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @AAA You are welcome :). Do not doubt to ask if you have more questions and your question it is well-defined and you can provide some code to check it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put it as a comment but I provide it as an answer to help if someone has the same error as @AAA. If you want to store your value you just have to put it as follows:

```
$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
```

but you have to aware that you have access to that `$row` (or that you are accessing in the right way to that content) before trying to assign it to a variable, in this case, inside the loop.